# How can I create a user specific login?

Tags: python

I want to be able, in Python, to make a login that allows users to enter a username and password and then make the program search through an array or dictionary to see if that username with the corresponding password exists. If it does, I want the program to log the user, in and load user specific page. How can I do this? Thanks.

Comment: Showing your research saves time for everyone. Please include what you've tried in your question, and describe what didn't work.

Comment: "Load user specific page", so you want to make a web application? In that case you might want to take a look at Flask or Django.

Comment: @Mr.goosberry, I have barely any code that would help, only two raw_input commands a sample dictionary.

Comment: Thanks @Sevanteri, I'll look at them.